# How To update Table Row in multiple Where Condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table Name: `EFL_EMP`

```
Company Locality    Geo Name    Code    address
EFL     SINDH       10023       Ali     100 main House HYD
EFL     SINDH       10024       Adil    101 main House HYD
EFL     SINDH       10025       Zahir   102 main House HYD
EFL     SINDH       10026       Naeem   103 main House HYD
EFL     SINDH       10027       Khalid  104 main House HYD
```

I Want to Update Geo Where Code Is 100, 102 OR 104 in one query.

Please guide me how.

Comment: What do you want to update `Geo` to? You can use an IN clause to specify multiple values.

Comment: Your question has the answer... You need to use OR in your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple SQL, that you could easily work out for yourself with some basic research.  You haven't really provided sufficient information in your question for a solution that will definitely work, but the syntax you are after is as follows:

```
update EFL_EMP
set Geo = 'Value to update to'
where Code in(100,102,104)
```